# Gradle sync failed: Cause: org/jetbrains/kotlin/parcelize/ide/ParcelizeGradleModel : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (168 ms)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am getting this error while syncing my gradle project. I am using jdk 1.7 version. And my
build.gradle  file is like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wicore.powercap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:32.0.0'
}
```